# Creating a model/optimization method to optimize a signal

Tags: python, optimization, probability

Suppose I have a system that is driven by a signal comprising 3 voltage levels (let's say -V1, 0, V1). I need to determine the composition of the signal that most accurately produces the desired output. The output is a single number that represents the current state of the system. The number of possible permutations for such a signal are too high to brute-force and find the global minimum i.e. exploring the entirety of the search space is impossible. However, I do have a model that simulates the system so I can still process several possible options. How can I find the best signal to produce the desired output (in other words, the signal that drives the system to the desired state)?

One method that I have right now involves producing a starting set (i.e. a small subset of the search space) of signals that align with a set of constraints, finding the signal that produces output closest to the desired output, and making modifications to this signal (i.e. fine tuning) in order to obtain the desired output. This final step is difficult for me, as I am manually doing this. One idea to automate this final step is to parametrize all possible modifications (for instance, parameter x1 = 1 adds a single -V1 'frame' to the signal, x1 = 2 adds two such frames, x1 = -1 removes a -V1 frame, and so on), and step through the set of possible modifications. But again, there's a lot of possibilities. To improve upon this, I explored the effect that modifications have on the system output. The effects of these modifications look somewhat predictable (the distributions of the changes in output they produce generally follow Gaussian distributions). But I'm not sure how to proceed from here. What models/schemes would you suggest I use? Can I use information from the distributions of changes produced by modifications to intelligently fine-tune the signal? How do I account for outliers (i.e. cases wherein the modification(s) to an initial signal produce a change in output that lies in the tail end of the distribution?

Edit: Forgot to mention, but the constraints on the signal would be length (the number of frames/steps in the signal must be less than or equal to a finite positive integer, N) and total potential (i.e. the sum of the voltages in the signal should equal an integer, V).

Comment: Does the signal repeat?  So, N steps in give N steps out?  Or does N steps in give 1 output?  How many steps?

Comment: It produces a single output i.e. a single number representing the current state of the system.

Comment: Additionally, the number of steps is finite (i.e. the length of the signal is a constraint).